# Have unknown length of navigation controllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, uinavigationcontroller

We are making a application where we use a API which returns an array of tree structured json objects. The objects have childs of the same type, so they also have childs of them self.
We wanna show these within a tableview inside a navigationcontroller.

So my question is how can we make use of navigationcontroller recursively? We don't know how many children's children they'll have.

Example JSON format [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JBXtaZPn)

**UPDATE**

Trying to explain it better, I've created this picture
[image]

My question is how can I dynamically add more UITableViewControllers? instead of creating hundreds of view controllers *(picture only shows 3)*

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON response?

Comment: yeah, sorry. Updated the question with pastebin link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already gave the answer: recurse. Delete all the table view controllers except the first one. Point the push segue from that first table view controller *at itself*. So now pushing will create another instance of that same kind of table view controller, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend do this in code. Because you don't want to keep pushing forever after you reach the end of your JSON data.

Example:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TestViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I threw together a quick sample project for you if you want it.
https://git.kenthinson.com/kenthinson/UnknownViewControllersSwift

Comment: I had something like that in mind. But having a segue to itself is much simpler.